How to make performance of my app better with similar sql-requests?
In laravel 10 / livewire 3 app I have a listing of news with related tags shows and debugging sql I see a lot of similar requests like :
SELECT *
FROM `tags`
WHERE `tags`.`id` in (41, 42)

...

SELECT *
FROM `tags`
WHERE `tags`.`id` in (40, 41, 42)

So if listing of news has 20 rows I see 20 such requests. I have component :
class ModelTag extends Component
{
    use AppCommonTrait;

    public int $id;
    public string $dataType;

    public $modelTaggables = [];

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('livewire.model-tag');
    }

    public function mount(int $id, string $dataType)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->dataType = $dataType;
        $this->readDbData();
    }

    protected function readDbData(): void
    {
        $modelType = $this->getModelType($this->dataType);
        $this->modelTaggables = Taggable
            ::getByTaggableType($modelType)
            ->getByTaggableId($this->id)
            ->with('tag')
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($TaggableItem) use($modelType) {
                return ['id'=> $TaggableItem->tag_id, 'name'=> $TaggableItem->tag->name];
            });

    }
}

I would like to make performance of my app better and reduce number of similar sql-requests.
How can I do it in this case ?

why not eager load the tags relation when you load your news

Listing of news is made in 1 component, but for any news separate ModelTag component are used as nested component - just wanted tp split functionality of components...

not sure how livewire works, but I would assume you need to pass the tags data from your parent component, rather than trying to load them from the db
